# Net::SNMP : get_request : automatic Human readable format?

Tags: perl, hex, snmp

i have an issue with Net::SNMP.

When i'm doing a unix snmpwalk like :

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c commu_key IP.XXX.XX.XX 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.2.1.2.XXX
```

i get :

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.42.1.2.2.1.2.3279 = Hex-STRING: 07 9F F4 XX
```

the Hex-STRING is an IP and each space is a dot.

but when i'm  using Net::SNMP in my script like :

```
my ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(
    -hostname => $ip,
    -community => 'commu_key',
    );
    if (!defined $session) {
     return 0;
    }
    my $result = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => [ $oid ],);
    if (!defined $session) {
     return 0;
    }
    my $ex = $result->{$oid};
```

but the $ex value is :

> $ex = 0x079ff4aXX

but i want it like the snmpwalk :/

can someone help me ?

Comment: So you want to output `07 9F F4 XX` instead of `0x079ff4aXX`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yes exaclty

Comment: What happened to the `a`? There are nine hex characters in your value. What does it really look like?

Comment: if that `a` is a typo and shouldn't really be there, this will do what you want: `$ex =~ s/^0x//; $ex = join ' ', $ex =~ m/../g;`

Comment: @stevieb: Funny. How do you know this? Do you work alongside the OP?

Comment: @Borodin I don't know, and I do not know the OP. The former SNMP output doesn't have the `a`, so I'm just curious whether it was added in by accident or not.

Comment: @stevieb: Ah, my apologies. I missed the ***if*** at the start of your comment. Sentences begin with a capital letter so as to make mistakes less likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT :

I did this :

```
sub hex_ip_converter {

my ($hex) = @_;
my $ip = undef;

my @array = ( $hex =~ m/../g );

shift (@array);

foreach my $tmp (@array) {
$ip = $ip . '.' . hex $tmp;
}
$ip =~ s/^.//; 
return $ip;
}
```

and it's working. ty for all your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't hard, and you should have at least made an effort

In order to get this out of the way, here's a subroutine that does what you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

say spaced_hex(0x079ff499);

sub spaced_hex {
    join(' ', unpack '(A2)*', sprintf('%08X', shift));
}
```

#### output

```
07 9F F4 99
```